# How to set upper and lower bounds of panZoom widget in Cytoscape?

Tags: cytoscape.js, cytoscape

I can initialize the object just fine:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.cy = cytoscapeService.cytoscape( Object.assign( {
        container : this.el.nativeElement,
    }, DATA_FLOW_CYTOSCAPE_CONFIG ) );
    this.cy.panzoom( Object.assign(
        { minZoom : 0, maxZoom : 10 }, // arbitrary numbers
        relateConfig.panzoomDefaults,
        ) );
```

However, no matter what numbers I use, or as my graph changes views, I can't seem to update the max/min appearance of the zoom slider. What I mean is, if the view can only be zoomed from, let's say, 1-2, the entire slider should slide between the min (1) and the max (2).

```
private runLayout() {
    this.cy.minZoom( 1e-50 );
    const layout = this.cy.layout( DATA_FLOW_LAYOUT_CONFIG );
    layout.on( 'layoutstop', () => {
        this.cy.minZoom( this.cy.zoom() );
        this.cy.panzoom( 'destroy' );
        this.cy.panzoom( Object.assign(
            { minZoom : this.cy.zoom() },
            relateConfig.panzoomDefaults,
            ) );
    } );
```

This adjusts the zoom limits, but also just restricts the amount of movement the slider has, it doesn't recalculate the min and max *slider* positions.

Does this make sense? Any thoughts?

Ex:

Initial slider movement range -

[|----------[]----------|]

View changed, bounds limited -

[--|--[]---|-------------]

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is with `Object.assign`.

```
this.cy.panzoom( Object.assign(
        { minZoom : this.cy.zoom() },
        relateConfig.panzoomDefaults,
        ) );
```

If you keep the defaults for panZoom stored somewhere (`relateConfig.panzoomDefaults` in my case), they won't get overwritten with `Object.assign`. Removing the values I wanted to be able to change immediately allowed me to change them as needed using `Object.assign`.